# Ubuntu 16.04 - RX 480

Tags: drivers, 16.04, amd-graphics

I have a PC running Ubuntu 16.04 and i am trying to get the AMDGPU drivers to work with my RX 480. When i try to install the drivers provided from AMD's website, the drivers seem to install properly, but after rebooting, i try to login and it just loops and wont allow me too. I have to switch to TTY and uninstall the drivers to gain access to my system again. Anyone have any ideas why the latest drivers wont work? Without them, the resolution is extremly low and it doesnt seem to have any generic drivers for the GPU in Ubuntu. My full PC specs are below.

Specs:
ASUS Crosshair-V z
FX-8350
16GB GSkill 1866 RAM
Sapphire Nitro+ RX 480 8GB

Thanks in advance!